# What book was this where a society celebrated risk taking?

Tags: story-identification, books

I read about a book here about a society in which risk taking was celebrated. In order to keep everyone on their toes traps were set which would need to be avoided on a daily basis. Going to the shops involved leaping over spike trap pits and pirouetting around swinging blades.

It was in [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/17533/would-a-sapient-species-have-to-be-the-dominant-species) link. I want to know which book this is.

Comment: Can you supply any more information, such as: when did you read it? What language/country? Anything about the main characters? What the cover looked like? Any additional details could help.

Comment: Hi there, I was the answerer. The book was a childrens book. I think it was called something like "trap world" or similar. The story line involved some children being abducted by off worlders. The children, having extensive martial training were able to defeat their abductors.

Comment: if you can give that in an answer, i could accept that.i tried googling trap world and could not get a positive search. will continue searching later and see what pops up.

Comment: Doesn't sound a lot like yours, but Philip E High's "Risk Economy" (Nebula #27, Feb 1958) used a similar idea. They were immortal and everyone had to take risks to keep the population down. The central character, an interstellar astronaut returned after 900 years, gets fed up with it and goes back into space, to the bafflement of his hosts who protest that unknown worlds are full of risk, but Earth is the only place where you get paid for taking a risk.